# Use the git hash code in Eclipse CDT build process

Tags: c, eclipse, git, hash

We need to pass the short git hash code `git rev-parse --short HEAD`, to the eclipse build process.
we use the Eclipse CDT internal builder.
I tried to store the git hash in a environment variable, using a pre-build script.
But in the build the variable is empty.
Our development system is based on windows eclipse CDT with a cross c compiler.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I find for the moment is write a eclipse plugin.
Working in progress...

Answer (score 0):

Project properties > C/C++ Build > Build Variables
Add string variable for example GIT_HASH string "$(shell git rev-parse HEAD)"
Or C Compiler preprocessor "GIT_HASH=$(shell git rev-parse HEAD)"